# Sharing Files on Blogger

Tags: file-sharing, blog, upload, blogger

I have created an account on Blogger and completed a blog entry but I want to attach a rar file containing source code. But, I came to know that Blogger does not allow to upload files. Can someone guide me through the process?

I have tried uploading files on Google Docs and sharing the link. When I share the file from Google Docs with visibility options set to everyone with the internet, it provides me with the link. Using this link I can go to the link showing the file but gives HTTP 404 not found message when I try to download the file.

This is the [Google Docs link](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B5fJZ50PYETkMmMyODE3YTAtNmQzNy00YWYyLWE5YzAtODFmNTVkMTI1N2I5&hl=en_US). I also downloaded Dropbox and tried to share the file there but it requires recipients to be mentioned explicitly with email addresses.

Comment: Google Docs link and the "Download" link work for me. Some visual studio project.

Comment: Also, whatever you place in the *Public* folder in your local Dropbox is shared publicly. Just give out the link (`http://dl.dropbox.com/u/youruserid/filename.rar` for *Dropbox/Public/filename.rar*).

Comment: Right click on file -> get shareable link to get a publicly accessible link for dropbox. More on that -> [How do you get a public link to a file in Dropbox that isn't in a public folder?](http://superuser.com/q/239301/4377)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to upload files other than image and video files to Blogger. You would have to use other file sharing websites like Dropbox to share such files.

Also, your Google Drive link works perfectly fine, feel free to use that link to share the same file with other people.