# Downloadable zip file in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, download, file-sharing, statistics

I am considering creating a blog in Blogger. I would like the blog to include a link to a zip file which would contain source code.

Two questions:

1. According to [Sharing Files on Blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/sharing-files-on-blogger]), it was not possible to upload other than image and video files to Blogger when the question was answered, in 2013. As a workaround, one had to provide rar / zip file links for example through Dropbox. Is this still the case?
2. Suppose my Blogger blog includes a Dropbox link to the zip file. How can I monitor how many times the file is downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1   Yes.   You need to provide links from a file-host.  Possibly Google Drive can be used (I'm not 100% sure if Drive takes rar/zip files).   But whatever file host you use, you need to get the link to the file from it, and put that link into your blog with the post editor or HTML-widget editor.

2   Monitor it using whatever tools your file host provides.   Blogger provides only very minimal monitoring tools, for your post popular posts.   It does allow Google Analytics to be set up for it.  But even that cannot know if a file was downloaded from an external source.